# PackagesNotFoundError when trying to install unrar with conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, unrar

I'm trying to install unrar with conda, with no luck. I installed other packages with no issues before.

Here's the commands I used:

```
user: conda activate username
user: conda install unrar
```

Which led to the follwing output:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - unrar

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I looked for the package on anaconda.org and didn't find it. I also tried using the command `conda install -c conda-forge unrar` as instructed in a post about a similar issue. Didn't work.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The package doesn't seem to be available for installation with conda, but you can install with pip, according to https://github.com/matiasb/python-unrar:

```
pip install unrar
```

In case you don't yet have pip installed in your environment, do `conda install pip`, and then install unrar with pip.

Comment: Also, note that this PyPI package only provides Python bindings. One must still install the UnRAR library independently.